# hyperlink that will follow its position / location every time I maximize or minimize, press ctrl - or + my screen in javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

How do I make a hyperlink follow its position / location every time I maximize or minimize, press ctrl - or + my screen? For example: If I press ctrl - or +, the hyperlink will follow the coordinates that was set and not stay or block other buttons and hyperlink when it gets bigger.

Question is so complicated but I wish I could make a video to make it clear.

Looking forward to anyone's kind assistance. Thank you very much in advance.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Launch a Web Page
// @namespace    http://your-website.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  Will launch a WebPage
// @author       me
// @match        https://example.com/*
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
'use strict';

// Function to launch the webpage
function launchWebpage() {
    // Adjust the URL to the webpage you want to launch
    const targetURL = 'https://example.com/';
    window.open(targetURL, '_blank');
}

// Create a hyperlink positioned on the upper middle of the screen
const launchLink = document.createElement('a');
launchLink.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
launchLink.textContent = 'WebPage';
launchLink.style.position = 'fixed';
launchLink.style.top = '10px';
launchLink.style.right = '30%';
launchLink.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
launchLink.style.color = 'white';
launchLink.style.padding = '10px';
launchLink.style.borderRadius = '5px';
launchLink.style.textDecoration = 'none';
launchLink.style.fontSize='18px';
document.body.appendChild(launchLink);

// Add event listener to the hyperlink
launchLink.addEventListener('click', launchWebpage);

})();
```

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for the comment and for sharing. From the prepend examples, which one will work? sorry, im a beginner :) thanks

Comment: @Teemu position.sticky makes my hypelink disappear :)

Comment: @Teemu no worries. thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like [sticky would do the trick](https://jsfiddle.net/3dwfaxvt/1) after all. Only that you've to bind the position to `left`, `right` doesn't seem to work with `sticky`.

Comment: Also, please prefer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) instead of W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

I think the style 'postion:fixed' is useful in Document,but maximize or minimize is controled by the browser,they are different levels.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello moon, thank you for commenting. I have edited my question as far as I can and hopefully it's clear.

Comment: I knew what you want ,but we can't do that, we can control an element's position in page, but if  browser  maximize or minimize,its out of our control ,because the browser  has the biggest control power

Comment: understood thanks